# List of emails, delete rows out of a table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

If I have a list of of email accounts in a .txt file, is there a way I can perform a mysql delete statement for each instance of the rows that contain the email account against a table?

We have a newsletter mailing list which around 600 emails are currently invalid, and we want an easier way of getting rid of them besides manually going in one by one to do it.

Comment: use the text file as a source of addresses to delete from a mysql table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the text file's contents as the source of addresses to delete from the database:

```
$addreses = file('emails.txt');
foreach($addresses as $address) {
    $safe_address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE (email = '$safe_address');";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

is the simplest form. You can do some things to optimize the process, such as creating a list of emails in quoted/comma-separated form and using `WHERE IN (...)` instead, to reduce the number of queries generated/executed.

Note that I'm using PHP as a pseudo-code placeholder, but the basic principle would be the same in pretty much any language.

Comment: +1 & Answer: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I'll probably be adjusting this to a BASH shell script.

Answer (score 5):

Use excel to turn the dataset into a comma separated string and then simply:

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE email IN ('example@aol.com', 'example2@aol.com')
```

Note that you will need to manually add the single quotes before and after each email address in excel as well.

Comment: This would work, except it's a lot of extra work for formatting.

Comment: You can use Excel string functions to automatically add the single quotes before and after each e-mail, before exporting.
=CONCATENATE("'", A1, "'")

Answer (score 0):

What about create the `delete statement` for `single email` then use `Microsoft excel` to complete the rest of the emails? by using the concatenate function and matching with the list of the selected emails

Comment: =D We use open office and not even sure how to do that in the first place.